# List of paragraph from a text file in java

Tags: java, file, text

I wanna make a list from a text file. Every elements in this list must represent a paragraph of the text.
The text is something like that:

```
Paragraph 1

bla bla bla <tab> bla bla bla


bla <tab> bla bla bla 

Paragraph 2

bla bla bla 
.
.
.


Paragraph 3
```

Every paragraph is separated from the other one 1, 2 or more space.
I tried this approach but it's not what I want.

```
public void fromFile2(String filename) throws IOException
   {
        String s = "";
        Path p = Paths.get(filename);
        BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
        while((s = r.readLine()) != null)
            b.add(s); // b is an ArrayList<String>
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried another approach, and it is like that:

```
public void carica(String filename) throws IOException
{
        String s = "";
        Path p = Paths.get(filename);
        BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
        String line = r.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            while(!line.isBlank() || !line.isEmpty())
            {
                s += line;
                line = r.readLine();
            }
            testo.add(s);
            s = "";
            line = r.readLine();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You say the paragraphs are separated by "space". Do you mean by blank lines? In other words: is a paragraph defined as consecutive lines without any blank lines in them?

Comment: Yes, every paragraph is separated by 1 or more blank lines

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the line is blank or empty like below --

```java
public void fromFile2(String filename) throws IOException {
        String s = "";
        List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
        Path p = Paths.get(filename);
        BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
        while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!s.isBlank() || !s.isEmpty())
            b.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

The output is -

```
[Paragraph 1, bla bla bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, Paragraph 2, bla bla bla . . ., Paragraph 3]
```

Comment: I'm confused - the text itself has lines spaced at the same distance as the paragraphs…

Comment: Every content of the paragraph must be with the title. I wanna something like this

[[Paragraph 1 bla bla bla], [Paragraph 2 bla bla bla], [Paragraph 3 bla bla bla]]